# Vue.js ignored when a blade is included in another blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have created a product card view in Laravel. the card has a simple "accordion" ('Show Details') - closed by default - that is managed by Vue.js as well as a Vue.js quantity counter that changes the weight value in grams if you add products. It all functions very well on the card's view and it looks like this (closed):
[image: card closed]

I have another view in which I query my DB for product names with Vue.js to display all products of the same name as a result. The problem is when the cards are displayed on that "parent" view, they all appear with the accordion open and the counter is not responsive. It looks like so:

[image: Cards open]

As you can see, the tailwindcss code is rendered without a problem but the Vue.js is being completely ignored (Although the parent view's Vue.js functions work perfectly) What am I doing wrong? What am I missing here? Why are the directives inside the included blade being ignored?

Here is the Vue.js method that manages the (product cards) views integration onto the parent (product name search) view:

```
        setGearItem(gearItem) {

            this.gearItem = gearItem;
            this.modal = false;
            console.log(gearItem);

            document.getElementById("displaySearch").innerHTML = "";

            axios.get('/send-name-get-ids/' + this.gearItem)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if (response.data.length === 0) {
                        document.getElementById("displaySearch").innerHTML = `"<strong>${gearItem}</strong>" was not found in our database. You can add it manually:`;
                        this.generalForm = true;
                        return;

                    } else {
                        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                            axios.get('/gearitem/' + response.data[i])
                                .then((response) => {
                                    console.log(response.data);
                                    document.getElementById("displaySearch").innerHTML += response.data;
                                    this.generalForm = false;
                                })
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    document.getElementById("displaySearch").innerHTML =
                                        "No items to display";
                                    console.log(error);
                                });
                        }
                    }
                });
        },
```

Comment: I don't think you can use vue to render multiple instances of a livewire component. Is this what you're doing or am I missing something?

Comment: It's not what I'm doing. The Vue and LiveWire manage two different things. The problem I have is that the system ignores the vue.js instructions in the html. I tried with only one card display and it's same result. I removed the for loop - same result. It has nothing to do with those things.

Comment: Even when I comment out the @livewire include from my card view - it still shows the cards with the accordion open. So It is not a LiveWire / Vue.js conflict.

Comment: In this case I would need more of the blade files code to understand

Comment: Do you want the card's blade? I'll post it.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the Vue method though. I don't think the card's blade would be of any help.

Comment: If you can provide the blade files, I will take a look and see if I can help

Comment: Where should I send them to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218396/discussion-between-nurge-and-francinaldo-almeida).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `.innerHTML` method as Vue.js ignores anything added via this method even if it's an AJAX. The solution consists on changing the controller to return a JSON and not a blade view, then using the JSON to populate a Vue.js component to create the item's card.  the `setGearItem()` method was changed like so:

```
        setGearItem(gearItem) {

            this.gearItem = gearItem;
            this.modal = false;
            console.log(gearItem);
            document.getElementById("displaySearch").innerHTML = "";
            this.displayItemCard = false;

            axios.get('/send-name-get-ids/' + this.gearItem)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.gearItemId = response.data[0];
                    if (response.data.length === 0) {
                        document.getElementById("displaySearch").innerHTML = 
                        `<p class="text-gray-700 ">
                        <strong class="capitalize">${gearItem}</strong>
                         was not found on our database. <br>You're free to add it manually! </p>`;

                        this.generalForm = true;
                        return;

                    } else {

                        this.displayItemCard = true;
                        
                    }
                });
        },
```

the `displayItemCard` just activates the card component on the view and displays the correct card according to the id.